# Gnuplot giving an extra point in dispersion plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data:
"ani_vs_16s.csv"

```
P_graminis_DSM_15220    P_jilunlii_ATCC_23019   93.02   99.2
P_graminis_DSM_15220    P_polymyxa_ATCC_842 69.03   94.5
P_jilunlii_ATCC_23019   P_polymyxa_ATCC_842 68.86   94.5
P_graminis_DSM_15220    P_riograndensis_SBR5    91.76   99
P_jilunlii_ATCC_23019   P_riograndensis_SBR5    92.76   98.5
P_polymyxa_ATCC_842 P_riograndensis_SBR5    68.57   94.2
P_graminis_DSM_15220    P_sonchi_X19-5  92.06   99.1
P_jilunlii_ATCC_23019   P_sonchi_X19-5  93.31   99.2
P_polymyxa_ATCC_842 P_sonchi_X19-5  68.88   94.8
P_riograndensis_SBR5    P_sonchi_X19-5  96.09   99
P_graminis_DSM_15220    P_sp._CAR114    91.38   99.4
P_jilunlii_ATCC_23019   P_sp._CAR114    92.45   99.3
P_polymyxa_ATCC_842 P_sp._CAR114    68.61   94.5
P_riograndensis_SBR5    P_sp._CAR114    96.31   99.2
P_sonchi_X19-5  P_sp._CAR114    95.61   99.4
P_graminis_DSM_15220    P_sp._CAS34 91.84   99.5
P_jilunlii_ATCC_23019   P_sp._CAS34 92.91   99
P_polymyxa_ATCC_842 P_sp._CAS34 68.63   94.7
P_riograndensis_SBR5    P_sp._CAS34 97.01   99.3
P_sonchi_X19-5  P_sp._CAS34 96.32   99.6
P_sp._CAR114    P_sp._CAS34 97.7    99.7
```

When I plot this points with gnuplot, an extra point appears on the plot (blue arrow). The table has 21 points, but 22 points are shown in the plot (note that there are 6 points in the lower left side of the plot).
[image]

I checked the data, but I was not able to find the problem. When I plot with LibreOffice Calc, no extra point appears. Is there some problem in my code?

```
set terminal  svg
set output “ani_vs_16S.svg”
set style rect fc lt -1 fs solid 0.15 noborder
set object rect from 95, graph 0 to 100, graph 1
set arrow from 0,98.5 to 100,98.5 nohead lw 8
plot "ani_vs_16s.csv" using 3:4 with points pt 7 ps 1
```

Comment: That's a different data file. You plot the third and fourth columns, but the data you show has only two columns

Comment: OK. I have corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This point seems to be a part of legend. Try to add notitle to the end of last line of your script.